# Magento 2: Invalid response line returned from server: HTTP/2 200

Tags: magento2, response

> **Invalid response line returned from server: HTTP/2 200**

I get the above error message when I want to log in to the extension manager.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Love to hear if someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. what error message you are facing

Answer (score 2):

I got this answer from stackchange from Asim.

A solution that worked for me is to replace the following code at

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php or
>   vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

Add Following changes in this function : `protected function parseHeaders($ch, $data)`

```
if ($this->_headerCount == 0) {
    $line = explode(" ", trim($data), 3);
    /* Remove this line */
    //if (count($line) != 3) {
/* Add this line */
if (count($line) < 2) {
  $this->doError("Invalid response line returned from server: " . $data);
}
$this->_responseStatus = intval($line[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you can update regexp in both places:

line 185: replace

`if (! preg_match('|^\d\.\d$|', $version)) {` with

`if (! preg_match('|^\d(\.\d)?$|', $version)) {`

line 517: replace

`if ($index === 0 && preg_match('#^HTTP/\d+(?:\.\d+) [1-5]\d+#', $line)) {` with

`if ($index === 0 && preg_match('#^HTTP/\d+(?:\.\d+|) [1-5]\d+#', $line)) {`

This should work for both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 response headers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution on this page *https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Sign-in-to-Magento-Marketplace-gt-quot-Invalid-response-line/td-p/111720* worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me is to replace the following code at:

> lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php or vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

Add Following changes in this function :

```
protected function parseHeaders($ch, $data)

if ($this->_headerCount == 0) {
    $line = explode(" ", trim($data), 3);
    /* Remove this line */
    //if (count($line) != 3) {
    /* Add this line */
if (count($line) < 2) {
   $this->doError("Invalid response line returned from server: " . 
$data);
}
$this->_responseStatus = intval($line[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I face with same issue but with stripe module. I suggest you to go
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Http/Response.php on line 517 
and add

```
if ($index === 0 && preg_match('#^HTTP/2 200#', $line)) {
 // Status line; ignore
 continue;
}
```

and on line 184 comment

```
// Set the HTTP version
    // if (! preg_match('|^\d\.\d$|', $version)) {
    //     #require_once 'Zend/Http/Exception.php';
    //     throw new Zend_Http_Exception("Invalid HTTP response version: $version");
    // }
```

Note. It's a hot fix. 
I hope it help you.

Comment: Changing core files directly is highly discouraged.

Comment: How do you make this change outside of vendor?

Comment: Look here https://bitbucket.org/nosro/extend-zend1/ (Note. write correct vendor name)